# How do I know odbc connection is busy or not before using it in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, odbc

Here I am using common open connection, so I want to know if connection is already busy or not before I perform executenonquery.

```
Dim cmd as OdbcCommand

cmd = new odbcCommand (s_sql, Con) 

 If Cnn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then Cnn.Open()

  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

cmd.dispose()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `busy`?

Comment: @AlexB. As I mentioned , I am using single open connection through out project when we are executing large query it holds connection for while and if immediately call other query with same connection  it shows connection is busy

Comment: Suppose you were to check and find out that it is busy; what would you do then?  How would you use that information?

Comment: No you didn´t mention that you use a single connection. But what is the purpose of doing so? Anyway this error occurs often in multi-threading environments. Also you should pack your command in an `using` block

Comment: TBH, you really can't. You should create the connection when you need it and then dispose of it when you are done. Also to actually answer your question, there isn't a way with that object to determine if it's busy, the only thing remotely possible to use is checking the connection state, but that doesn't mean "it's busy".

Comment: @AlexB.  Thanks for Reply .. Actually purpose for checking that is  I am try to execute some insert query some times that same query execute with no issue but some times cmd.executenonquery throws an exception object reference . Strange thing is when this error occurs record is get inserted to table still it gets error. so I think it might be connection busy issue or may be something else

Comment: I´m with @Çöđěxěŕ here. There is no benefit for using a single shared connection. Just create a connection whenever you need it and dispose it right after.

Comment: @AlexB. Ok thank you.. Just tell me one thing Closing and opening connection each time  , Is that time consuming ? because I have to enter large number of records within seconds . so is it take time to re- open connection ??

Comment: That is highly dependent on your environment: Which DBMS? Which Server Hardware? What is a `large number of records (1K, 1M, 1B) ? What kind of consuming  are you talking about (Memory, CPU, Performance)? With a shot in the dark you mean the latter and opening a connection will not affect your performance compared to the actual Inserts. Especially if you enclose multiple values in one roundttrip.

Comment: Havin said that, just test it on your system and measure the performance.